# BrowserStack Selenium local authentication dialog

Tags: c#, selenium, remote-access, browserstack

We're trying to use BrowserStack in local mode to hit our AUT on our internal network. I've got it configured so that I'm getting the remote browser session, but as soon as I try to direct it to our app's (or any) URL within the firewall via **Chrome**, the browser throws up a dialog complaining that the connection is not private and asking for a user name and password. This is not a normal pop-up and we can't automate it with Selenium, so it stops us dead.

When accessed via a desktop browser session the system knows who I am and opens for me with all appropriate permissions etc. It doesn't know who... or what... is coming through the remote session, thus the requirement to authenticate, I guess?

We see slightly different behavior with **Edge**: No pop-up, it just clocks until time-out. OTOH, if I just try to launch **Edge** in BrowserStack Live, I get a message saying "If you're behind a corporate firewall, disable SSL inspection for *.browserstack.com", and then I get thrown out.

I've been scouring everything I can find about local to see if there's some way I can create the remote session with an 'identity' (I'm talking network identity, not B'stack user name/access key) and all I'm finding are things that pertain to proxy servers. As far as I know, there is not a proxy server at play here, so I'm really kinda up in the air.

Are there folks with experience with B'stack local mode who might be able to provide some insight?

rabbit

Comment: Could possibly be proxy-related... maybe see this page for setting browserstack proxy flags:  https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/binary-params

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the local binary downloaded and running on your machine...it could cause this to happen.

You can download it here:

https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing/automate#command-line

After you have it unzipped on your local machine...open up terminal:

./BrowserStackLocal --key yourkeyhere

Once it is running on your local machine, try to open up BrowserStackLive and run your manual tests.

Are you also having issues with automated tests not completing or just the manual testing of the website?